# Gulp - Laravel Elixir picking wrong directory

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have this in my gulpfile;

```
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.scripts([
    'app.js',
    'public/assets/bower/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/boostrap-tagsinput.js'
], 'app.js');

mix.sass('app.scss')
   .browserify('app.js');

});
```

But when I run `gulp` I get:
`resources/assets/js/public/assets/bower/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/boostrap-tagsinput.js <-- Not Found`

Not sure why that is as I've put the right path in the gulpfile.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define as absolute path:

```
'./public/assets/bower/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/boostrap-tagsinput.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to configure base path in `elixir.json`. Here is an example

```
{
  "publicPath": "public"
}
```